# Send serialized form values to php

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have this form with radio buttons:

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="try" value="radio1" checked="checked" id="r1"/>
    <label for="r1">radio1</label>

    <input type="radio" name="try" value="radio2" checked="checked" id="r2"/>
    <label for="r2">radio2</label>
</form>
```

I have this jquery code to send the values:

```
<script>
function sendValues() {
    var str = $("form").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "Get",
        url: "samepage.php",
        data: str,
        succes : function(data) {
            result = data;
        } 
    }); 
 }
$(":radio").click(sendValues);
sendValues();
</script>
```

Using firebug I can se that the code returns /sampage?try=radio1 if I choose radio button with value radio1.

I then try to send this value to a php variable with:

```
$value = $_GET['try'];
```

But echo $value gives nothing. My questions is, thus, how can I send serialazed values with jquery to php variables.

Comment: are you sure the request is initiating and is reaching to server properly? I see two issues. In the code spelling of `success` is wrong. Moreover, in your comment, you said that it returns you `/sampage?try=radio` which should be `/samepage.php?try=radio`

Comment: are you sure your path is to samepage.php is correct?? i checked your code on my local and its working correctly

Comment: No, not sure at all if the request is reachning the server, but as I stated in my question, I can see a response with /samepage?try=radio1 in firebug. And I can print that using    $("#somediv").text(str); which gives radio=radio1 The path is just att spelling mistake, sorry about that, but It's not the issue.

Comment: @user1009453 what response are you getting in firebug

Comment: GET http://localhost/riorank/samepage.php?try=radio1

Comment: @user1009453 click on the link in firebug and check the response tab

Comment: Well, the response is just the html page, noting else. But did you actually manage to echo out the value of the try variable using php. If so, could you post your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="try" value="radio1" checked="checked" id="r1"/>
    <label for="r1">radio1</label>

    <input type="radio" name="try" value="radio2" checked="checked" id="r2"/>
    <label for="r2">radio2</label>
</form>
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
function sendValues() {
    var str = $("form").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "Get",
        url: "samepage.php",
        data: str,
        success : function(data) { //syntax error its success
           $("#result").html(html);
        } 
    }); 
 }
$(":radio").click(sendValues);
sendValues();
</script>
```

And in samepage.php

```
echo $value = $_GET['try'];
```

Comment: Nope this doesn't wok for me. If I navigate to samepage.php after submit I only get Notice: Undefined index: try. But if I manually type in http://localhost/samepage.php?try=radio2 the variable is echoed. Conclusion is that $value doesn't pick up the get reguest when sent through ajax. I don't understand why